# unable to install phpMyAdmin on php 7.1

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, centos7

I have install php 7.1 on centos 7.2
when I install phpMyAdmin:

```
yum -y install phpMyAdmin
```

failed, happen below:

```
Package php71w-common-7.1.8-2.w7.x86_64 is obsoleted by php-common-7.1.9-1.el7.remi.x86_64 which is already installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libtidy.x86_64 0:5.4.0-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package phpMyAdmin.noarch 0:4.4.15.10-2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-zip for package: phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.10-2.el7.noarch
Package php71w-common-7.1.8-2.w7.x86_64 is obsoleted by php-common-7.1.9-1.el7.remi.x86_64 which is already installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.10-2.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-zip
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php-zip
           Available: php-pecl-zip-1.15.0-1.el7.remi.7.1.x86_64 (remi-php71)
               php-zip = 1:1.15.0-1.el7.remi.7.1
           Available: php-pecl-zip-1.15.1-1.el7.remi.7.1.x86_64 (remi-php71)
               php-zip = 1:1.15.1-1.el7.remi.7.1
           Available: php55w-common-5.5.38-1.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-zip
           Available: php56w-common-5.6.31-1.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-zip
           Available: php70w-common-7.0.22-2.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-zip
           Available: php71w-common-7.1.8-2.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-zip
           Installed: php-common-7.1.9-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php71)
               Not found
           Available: php-common-7.1.8-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php71)
               Not found
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I cannot find php-common-5.4, where is php-zip?

Who can help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's saying that `php-common-7.1.9-1.el7.remi.x86_64` is installed but cannot be found? Did you install it correctly?

Comment: I installed it with:  yum --enablerepo=remi install php71-php-common, No error.

Comment: Which PHP version do you want ?  Don't mix various provider (webtatic + remi).  phpMyAdmin 4.4 in EPEL is NOT compatible with recent PHP Version. (version 4.7 is available in "remi"). Try to install php-pecl-zip "before" phpMyAdmin, and disable webtatic

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer installing phpMyAdmin manually - you have more control:

1. Go to https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/ and download the latest version
2. Uncompress the downloaded archive in /usr/share/phpmyadmin
3. Create an alias within your Apache configuration. Something like this:

> ```
> Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
>
> <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/>
>    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
>    Require all granted
> </Directory>
>
> <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/>
>    Require all granted
> </Directory>
>
> <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/>
>     Require all granted
> </Directory>
>
> <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib/>
>     Require all granted
> </Directory>
>
> <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/frames/>
>     Require all granted
> </Directory>
> ```

4. Copy config.sample.inc.php to config.inc.php and adjust the settings inside.
5. Login to yoursite.com/phpmyadmin and confirm the installation